# PHP - Does an index of an array variable that is reference also a reference?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

```
$cars = array(
     array('name' => 'Toyota', price => 10000, ...),
     array('name' => 'Ford', price => 20000, ...),
     ...
);

foreach($cars as &$car)
{
   do_something($car['name']);
}
unset($car);

function do_something($name)
{
    ....
}
```

In do_something() function, is $name a reference or a value? If it is a reference, how do I just retrieve the value in the loop and pass that in the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `$name` in `do_something()` function is not a reference, it is not pass by reference, only pass the value of `$car['name']` to `$name`.

If you want to pass by reference, you could do like below, pass `$car` as reference.

```
$cars = array(
     array('name' => 'Toyota', price => 10000),
     array('name' => 'Ford', price => 20000)
);

foreach($cars as &$car)
{
   do_something($car);
}

var_dump($cars);

function do_something(&$car)
{
    $car['name'] .= '_changed';
}
```